# How to declare pointer-of-pointer using iso_c_binding?

Tags: c, fortran, interop, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am writing an **iso_c_binding** in Fortran to call a C-function with the below prototype

```
int zmat_run(
    const size_t inputsize,
    unsigned char *inputstr, 
    size_t *outputsize, 
    unsigned char **outputbuf,
    const int zipid, 
    int *ret, 
    const int iscompress
);
```

My question is how do I declare `unsigned char **outputbuf`, a pointer that is used inside the c-function to allocate output buffer, in this interface?

Also, what data type I should be using in Fortran as the real parameter to pass to this `outputbuf` parameter? should it be allocatable? (if it is allocated inside the c-function)?

I currently drafted this module, but haven't tested it (I doubt it will work).

```
module zmatlib
  use iso_c_binding, only: c_char, c_size_t, c_ptr, C_NULL_CHAR
  interface
    integer(c_int) function zmat_run(inputsize, inputbuf, outputsize, outputbuf, zipid, ret, level) bind(C, name="zmat_run")
      use iso_c_binding
      integer(c_size_t), value :: inputsize
      integer(c_int), value :: zipid, level
      integer(c_size_t),  intent(out) :: outputsize
      integer(c_int),  intent(out) :: ret
      character(kind=c_char),  intent(in)  :: inputbuf(*)
      character pointer(c_ptr),intent(out) :: outputbuf
    end function zmat_run
  end interface
end module
```

Comment: At the least `character pointer(c_ptr)` isn't a Fortran thing.  Could you revisit the Fortran block you drafted to be more syntactically correct in what you think is appropriate?

Comment: Yes, I know that wasn't valid, just a place holder. Googled but only find examples of pointers, but not pointer of pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *type (C_PTR), intent (out)*.  Then you will need to use Fortran function *c_f_pointer* to associate the C pointer with a Fortran pointer.  Probably of type *C_CHAR*.

Comment: Thank you, it works! here is the [interface declaration](https://github.com/fangq/zmat/blob/master/fortran90/zmatlib.f90#L63-L71), and here is my [test code](https://github.com/fangq/zmat/blob/master/test/f90/testzmat.f90). However, the only remaining question is how do I "free" the [`myout` pointer](https://github.com/fangq/zmat/blob/master/test/f90/testzmat.f90#L32) on the fortran side? `valgrind` detects a memory leak in this test code.

Comment: another follow-up question - is there any risk of using fortran native types vs `iso_c_binding` c-types? for example, for `c_size_t`, I used a `integer(kind=8)` on the fortran side, does this cause any side effect? similarly for `character(kind=c_char)` vs the native `character` type.

Comment: Re my earlier question on freeing the c-allocated buffer, I added a c-function to call free, and added it to the interface. https://github.com/fangq/zmat/blob/master/fortran90/zmatlib.f90#L115-L124

Comment: The risk of not using the kind values declared in `ISO_C_BINDING` is that the compiler's kind values may not match C's. Why not use `C_SIZE_T`? `kind=8` is inherently non-portable.

Comment: As you did, since the memory was allocated on the C side, it is best to free the memory on the C side.  You can optionally nullify the Fortran pointer.